# Get body innertext webbrowser in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This code does not work because 
*'innertext' is not a member of  'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection'.*
Does anyone know what to do?
Thanks.

```
 Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
       Dim body As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body").innerText
 Loop
```

Comment: It's not working because it's a collection of elements. have you tried `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.innerText
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`GetElementById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (without 's') instead of `GetElementsById` (with 's') :

```
Dim body As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName("body").innerText
```

The former method returns `HtmlElement` which has `InnerText` property.